# Can I find the etrog "hay"?

Tags: product-recommendation, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

Until about 10 years ago, etrogim were wrapped in hemp (flax weed). It was messy, but it kept the etrogim fresh for much longer than the foam does. I also find that the combination of the foam and the etrog box (esp. silver ones) create more moisture, and eventually, mold.

Is there some place (in NYC area) where I can get etrogim wrapped in hay or just the hay itself? (I can do the wrapping.)

FYI - Most years, when I wrapped it in the hay and kept it in the cardboard box, it shrank minimally and did not dry out to the point where I was able to use it the following year. My current year's etrog is still fine and yellow and fresh-looking. If I can find some hay, now, I may be able to salvage it for this coming Succot.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10716/esrog-flax-on-woolen-clothes

Comment: (I'm told it also used to cause brown spots...)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the same _etrog_ the following year unless you are enough of an expert to determine that it is still kosher. Also, last year was a _shemita_ year so the _etrogim_ from this past _sukkot_ have _kedushat shvi'it_ (assuming they were grown in Israel) and are therefore subject to _biur peirot shvi'it_ and should be properly disposed of by _Tu B'Shvat_.

Comment: @Daniel I'm not, but my rav is, and a friend of mine who sells etrogim is. Can you provide a source that indicates that Shvi'it etrogim may not be reused for the same mitzvah the following year?

Comment: @DanF See #4 [here](https://torahmitzion.org/learn/fruit-kedushat-shviit/)

Comment: @DanF See also [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64185/1713) to another MY question

Answer (score -1):

[This link](http://www.paradisefibers.com/hemp-roving-loose-fiber.html?fee=3&fep=52316&gclid=Cj0KEQiA-4i0BRCaudDcrrnDi6kBEiQAZSh5fyYJ1M-WJ4X873MxRD0-NpiqLHTmnAMnY8W9yeHfd9QaApTx8P8HAQ) might be worth a try.

Comment: Because the vast majority of posts under 30 characters are very very low quality. Here too you can add some info about where the link goes and why you think it might be helpful, both in case of link-rot, and also for people who don't like clicking random links or can't right now (eg. mobile).

Comment: "or can't right now ", like me ... right now... b/c my current connection blocks many sites.